# a warning message in building and running C in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, sublimetext3

When I build and run C using Sublime Text 3, a warning message show up.

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
```

Actually, it is my first time to use Sublime Text 3 for C programming, so I wonder how to take care of this warning message.

My source code and the output are as below.

soruce:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 3;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

output:

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
3
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

These are executed in Mavericks(Mac OS)

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compile c as c++. Having not used sumblime before, I don't know where to change the compile options. If it generates a Makefile, maybe you'd want to post that too

Answer (score 3):

Does this mean you have saved your file as **file.cpp** instead of **file.c**? (Sorry, I can not comment, I have few points.)

Comment: You now have 81 points; that's enough to comment (and even 61 points would have been enough -- you only need 50 to be able to comment everywhere).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Only after I posted my answer then I got 81 points a dozen of minutes later (from elsewhere), but before that I had less than 50. I do not lie.

Comment: Congratulations.  I didn't say you lied.  I didn't know whether you knew what the limit was, and it was possible that you had 61 points when you first answered (and it was also possible -- and in fact was -- the case that you had fewer points when you posted and you then got a flurry of upvotes; your net rep has more than doubled in the last hour).